# Graph diameter and average pairwise distance

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

How do I prove that for a graph G, I can always find a constant c>0 such that

$$
\frac{\text{diameter}(G)}{\text{average  pairwise distance} (G)} > c
$$

where 
$$
\text{average pairwise distance }= \frac{\sum_{v_1,v_2\in V}\text{distance}(v_1, v_2)}{\binom{n}{2}}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, 
$$
\operatorname{diam}(G) = \max\{\operatorname{dist}(v_1,v_2) : v_1,v_2 \in V\}
$$
and
$$
 \operatorname{AvgPairDist}(G) \leq \max\{\operatorname{dist}(v_1,v_2) : v_1,v_2 \in V\} = \operatorname{diam}(G)
$$
So 
$$
\frac{\operatorname{diam}(G)}{\operatorname{AvgPairDist}(G)} \geq \frac{\operatorname{diam}(G)}{\operatorname{diam}(G)} = 1
$$
...or am I missing something?

Comment: The correct problem should state that for any constant $c > 0$, prove that there exists a connected graph such that $$diam(G)/apd(G) > c$$.